# Proc Freq not combining

Tags: sas

I am trying to compare tumors or not for 2 different groups. However, when I run the Proc Freq it shows the results in different charts. What should I do differently?

Code

```
 proc freq data=tCto502 order=data;
  by Group;
  table TumorYesorNoCoded*Group / fisher;
  run;
```

I got the following notes.

```
NOTE: No statistics are computed for TumorYesorNoCoded * Group because Group has fewer than 2
      nonmissing levels.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      Group=50
NOTE: No statistics are computed for TumorYesorNoCoded * Group because TumorYesorNoCoded has fewer
      than 2 nonmissing levels.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      Group=Control
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Js3a.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBZ5n.png)
[image: Results I am trying to get layout wise to get my p-value and such]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the group by, since the `table` argument is already combining `TumorYesorNoCoded*Group`.

Just run:

```
proc freq data=tCto502;
  table TumorYesorNoCoded*Group / fisher;
  run;
```

Edited:

After the question was updated with the desired output, to get the exactly the same result, you can run:

```
proc freq data=tCto502 order=internal;
table Group*TumorYesorNoCoded / fisher NOCOL NOPERCENT NOROW;
run;
```

Comment: It worked but I realized it isn't giving me what I need. I don't think I explained it the best.

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. Do you want to explain better what you want? I see that you added a new table to your question. I don't know if I understood it, but it does not make much sense to me. In your table you seem to want control group to be in the rows and "Group 50" to be in the columns. However, they are two different values of the same variable, that is, they are mutually exclusive groups (there is not a single case of the control group that also belongs to the "Group 50"). Also, in the data you provided, there is no case in the control group who does not have a tumor.

Comment: I would recommend you to try to fill manually this excel table you provided with the cases from the output of the code that I wrote to you. To check if it does make sense. Anyway, if you wanna try SAS to combine group with group itself and tumor, it can be done, but I dont see why: ```proc freq data=tCto502;
table Group*TumorYesorNoCoded*Group / fisher;
run;```  You also can remove the percentages, if you want just to obtain simple frequency counts: ```proc freq data=tCto502;
table Group*TumorYesorNoCoded*Group / fisher NOCOL NOPERCENT NOROW;
run;```

Comment: I edited the table with numbers for clarification per your suggestion. Thank you for all of your explanations!

Comment: Ok, I also updated my answer to try to approach the most your request

Comment: I would imagine group is a numeric, so a format is the proper way to deal with the labels (and may already be on the dataset).

Comment: Dataset was provided only as image. One of the Groups is "Control". It is also left aligned, so I assumed as a string

Comment: We know it's numeric, though, from the log and results tables, no?  But either way, images are not good sources of this.

Comment: Thanks Joe, you are right. I see it in the log. Do you wanna show me how to change a value label without knowing the value of the variable? I don't know this one.